# In C# 3.0 we use "var" what is its alternative in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, mef, var

I am learning plug able architecture in .Net using Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF.)
I saw sample code on the net, but when I tried to implement it I got stuck at one point.

The code was using:

```
 var catalog = new AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
 var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateResolver());
```

This `var` is available on C# 3.0 where as I am coding in C# 2.0.

What is the alternative of above two statements? How can I make them work in c# 2.0 using VS 2005?

---

i tried this bt its saying now

Error 1 **The type or namespace name 'AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\MEFDemo\MEFDemo\Program.cs 31 13 MEFDemo

where as i have added referance to SystemComponentModel.Composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the use of type inference in C# 3.0.

When using the keyword

```
var
```

in c# 3.0 the compiler infers the type. See [scott guthries explanation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/15/new-orcas-language-feature-anonymous-types.aspx)

In c# 2.0 you have to declare the type of the variable the same as c# 1.1

e.g.

```
Type variableName = new Type();
```

Making you above code example

```
AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog catalog = new AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateResolver());
```

HTH

Comment: Anonymous types and implicitly typed variables are separate features. Anonymous types aren't particularly useful without "var", but the sample in the question doesn't use anonymous types at all.

Comment: Post Edited. Thanks for pointing that out Jon I got my wording mixed up.

Comment: As an additional help, you can hover the mouse over the "var" keyword to find out what the inferred type is.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, `var` forces the compiler to determine (infer) the *compile-time* type of a variable based on it's "initializer" -- effectively, an expression to the right from `=` sign. Here the types are obvious:

```
AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog catalog = 
    new AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
CompositionContainer container = 
    new CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateResolver());
```

And make sure you add `using System.ComponentModel.Composition;` statement. Plus, be advised that `AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog` was renamed to `AssemblyCatalog`.

Comment: i tried this bt its saying now

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\MEFDemo\MEFDemo\Program.cs 31 13 MEFDemo


where as i have added referance to SystemComponentModel.Fomposition

Comment: I'm not sure your apparent condescension is necessary, if the OP "obviously" doesn't understand, is there any need to point that out?

Comment: I removed the "apparent condescension", it's a down-vote magnet to what is otherwise a complete and comprehensive question.

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog catalog = new 
    AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

CompositionContainer container = new 
    CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateResolver());
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in C# are still strongly typed. `var` is implicit typing - see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

In most cases it just means you have to type less, but there are cases where it's necessary - in the second example on the page I've linked to:

> `var` must be used because the result
>   is a collection of anonymous types,
>   and the name of that type is not
>   accessible except to the compiler
>   itself.

Answer (score 0):

*var* is a C# 3.0 keyword and does nothing other than inferring the strong type from the initialization value.

In the absence of var, you manually do what the compiler is doing behind the scenes; you specify the type of the variable in the declaration.

Hence;

```
AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog catalog = new 
    AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

CompositionContainer container = new 
    CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateResolver());
```

Answer (score 0):

MEF uses LINQ, so it requires .NET 3.5.  You won't have any luck trying to use it on .NET 2.0.